# Java error on CSS

Tags: java, css, javafx, controlsfx, jfoenix

Today java is going crazy with CSS styling, I think it could be a problem of dependencies, my dependences are:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jfoenix</groupId>
        <artifactId>jfoenix</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
        <version>8.40.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.jensd</groupId>
        <artifactId>fontawesomefx</artifactId>
        <version>8.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

and the errorr is:

```
Dic 22, 2017 11:26:29 AM javafx.scene.CssStyleHelper calculateValue
WARNING: Could not resolve '-fx-text-background-color' while resolving 
lookups for '-fx-text-fill' from rule '*.label' in stylesheet  jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar!/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.bss
dic 22, 2017 11:26:29 AM javafx.scene.CssStyleHelper calculateValue
WARNING: Could not resolve '-fx-text-background-color' while resolving lookups for '-fx-text-fill' from rule '*.label' in stylesheet jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar!/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.bss
dic 22, 2017 11:26:29 AM javafx.scene.CssStyleHelper calculateValue
WARNING: Could not resolve '-fx-text-background-color' while resolving lookups for '-fx-text-fill' from rule '*.label' in stylesheet jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar!/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.bss
dic 22, 2017 11:26:29 AM javafx.scene.CssStyleHelper calculateValue
WARNING: Could not resolve '-fx-text-background-color' while resolving lookups for '-fx-text-fill' from rule '*.label' in stylesheet jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar!/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.bss
dic 22, 2017 11:26:30 AM javafx.scene.CssStyleHelper calculateValue
WARNING: Could not resolve '-fx-text-background-color' while resolving lookups for '-fx-text-fill' from rule '*.check-box' in stylesheet jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar!/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.bss
dic 22, 2017 11:26:33 AM javafx.scene.CssStyleHelper calculateValue
WARNING: Could not resolve '-fx-text-background-color' while resolving lookups for '-fx-text-fill' from rule '*.check-box' in stylesheet jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar!/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.bss
dic 22, 2017 11:26:34 AM javafx.scene.CssStyleHelper calculateValue
WARNING: Could not resolve '-fx-text-base-color' while resolving lookups for '-fx-text-fill' from rule '*.combo-box-base' in stylesheet jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar!/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.bss
 dic 22, 2017 11:26:34 AM javafx.scene.CssStyleHelper calculateValue
  WARNING: Could not resolve '-fx-text-base-color' while resolving lookups for '-fx-text-fill' from rule '*.combo-box-base' in stylesheet jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar!/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.bss
```

I cannot find the cause ...

Comment: Have you tried workaround from https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/issues/370/using-controlsfx-causes-css-errors-and ? It looks like it is JDK bug like https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8088578 .

Comment: Does not work, even if I remove my custom stylesheet -.- really bad...

Comment: any solutions for this problem yet?

Comment: @user158037 what was the workaround? link seems dead now

Answer (score 0):

I used **CheckComboBox** from the **controlsfx** library and had similar warnings. Actually, this warnings occured when I tried to initialize items of **CheckComboBox** (checkComboBox.getItems().addAll(items) method). In my case the usage of **Platform.runLater** method helped me to overcome this warnings. This method allows to run some code from **JavaFX Application Thread** context.